# What is the correct way to create an object that I don't need a reference to in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, warnings, compiler-warnings, tslint, unused-variables

I need to create an object, and I don't need the reference to it once it's created. I have this code:

```
const myPieChart = new Chart(context, {
    type: "pie",
    data: dataSource
});
```

But I get the warning `'myPieChart' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)` and SolarLint says `Remove this useless assignment to variable "myPieChart".sonarlint(typescript:S1854)`

If I instead use this code:

```
new Chart(context, {
    type: "pie",
    data: dataSource
});
```

TSLint complains: `unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)tslint(1)`

Surely there must be a proper way to write this code without just disabling one of the warnings?

Comment: Is `Chart` callable without `new`? Try it. If not, disabling the warning really is the right (and only) way to go - it feels inelegant, but due to Chart's API design, it may not be possible to avoid it. If you *know* something isn't an error and don't see a better way, don't be afraid to tell the linter to ignore it.

Comment: The code only works when `new` is present. By the way, is it possible to disable this warning in my entire project, not just on this one line?

Comment: Unfortunate. Guess you need to disable the warning. Don't feel bad about it, it's the least inelegant solution available. Don't disable it project-wide - better to whitelist these sorts of lines instead, that way the linter can warn you of potential mistakes not related to Chart

Comment: @AaronFranke Yes it's possible to disable that warning completely. in your `tsconfig.json` file you add `"allowUnusedLabels": true` to your `compilerOptions` object.

Comment: It seems strange that `new Chart(...)` without assigning it to a variable would not be allowed. I would just disable that `no-unused-expression` linting rule, since it's quite a common pattern to use.

Comment: How do I disable the `no-unused-expression` linting rule? The above `"allowUnusedLabels": true` disables the warning for `const myPieChart = new`... but I don't know how to disable `no-unused-expression`. If anyone would like to post this information as an answer I will accept it since it's the best solution for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
function main(){
  return new Chart(context, {
    type: "pie",
    data: dataSource
  });
}
main();
```

or

```
export const myPieChart = new Chart(context, {
    type: "pie",
    data: dataSource
});
```